# Openshift redirect to https using flask-base example

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, openshift

I'm trying to run my flask based app on free gear on Openshift only on https. Following [this](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS) - I have added the `.htaccess` file to the root of my repo but it seems to be ignored, as it is not redirecting. The article talks about a `wsgi` directory but I have none, so I'm not sure about the place. I have created the app using [this example](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/flask-base):

```
$cat .htaccess 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding for the OpenShift setup is that the `.htaccess` file can only be used in conjunction with static files and not the dynamic part of your application. To use the standard Apache/mod_wsgi setup you would have to instead use a WSGI middleware that wraps your Flask application to force the redirection.

The only alternative I can offer is that you side step the standard Apache/mod_wsgi installation they provide and instead use mod_wsgi-express as outlined in:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/01/using-alternative-wsgi-servers-with.html

When using mod_wsgi-express then I would be able to explain a way of adding an additional Apache configuration snippet to trigger the redirection.

---

UPDATE 1

FWIW, my understanding that this would only be possible for the 'wsgi/static' directory in the older style of setting up OpenShift was because the actual WSGI application would have been mapped with the WSGIScriptAlias directive.

Except for file system access permissions, being setup in a Directory block in the Apache configuration file, there was never a specific intention in the way WSGIScriptAlias worked in mod_wsgi for a .htaccess file within a directory referred to by the WSGIScriptAlias directive to be consulted. It looks like that is actually possible, at least with Apache 2.X, not sure about Apache 1.3 although possibly it worked there as well.

So it looks like the OpenShift folks have stumbled across something which is possible that isn't documented for mod_wsgi and which I as the person who wrote mod_wsgi didn't even expect to necessarily work. I am going to have to think this one through now, as there may be things one can do in the .htaccess file which can screw with how mod_wsgi works. It may also open up some strange possibilities for what users with no access to the main Apache configuration can do as well, possibly good, but also maybe bad.

Reiterating what I said in other comments, OpenShift has supported two different ways of setting up a WSGI application. The older way was to create a subdirectory called 'wsgi' and in that add an 'application' file which would be the WSGI script file. There could also be a 'wsgi/static' directory for static files. The newer way they document and now seem to recommend is to create a 'wsgi.py' file in the root directory of the project for the WSGI script file. The name of this can be overridden with an environment variable set with 'rhc set-env'.

I haven't checked for what they generate for the configuration for the older arrangement, but they could have setup the Apache configuration to allow Apache overrides in the 'wsgi' subdirectory, meaning that a .htaccess file can be placed there. This wouldn't be normal practice, but it seems they found it to work and would allow certain types of overrides.

If they have done that for the 'wsgi' subdirectory, it doesn't seem though they did the same thing for the root directory when they switched to preferring a 'wsgi.py' in the top directory.

Either way, using mod_wsgi-express as I mention will give you back a much higher level of control over how Apache and mod_wsgi is setup. The pre canned configuration isn't really flexible and some of the guesses made for the configuration based on gear size aren't necessarily appropriate as they don't take into consideration the requirements of the application itself, which only the user would know.

Comment: Thanks a lot it made me realize what are the options and that I'm OK with the openshift default `mod_wsgi` setup so I just created a new app with that base and  `.htaccess` works like charm. I'm marking it as answered as this is really good article which gives enough insight to figure out what you need. Cheers

Comment: After reading a bit more it actually left me a even more confused :)  I'm not familiar with python web development I'm using python for ages but this is my first python webapp. Anyway, following [openshift's quickstart for flask](https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html) solved it for me. I don't know how exactly is the `mod_wsgi `set up but putting `.htaccess` in the root works. I can even put WSGI specific stuff like `WSGIPassAuthorization` in and it works. I'd say for simple apps it is enough. Thanks a lot for the clarification, it helped.

Comment: Yes, ``WSGIPassAuthorization`` would work if ``Auth`` override is allowed, which if an ``AllowOverride All`` was done would cover it.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file needs to go inside of your wsgi folder within your python application.

Comment: Well I have none, see the [github repo](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/flask-base) which I used as a base for the project. There is no `wsgi` directory, it does not use the standard Apache/mod_wsgi but instead uses the `app.py` approach, so I switched to the Apache/mod_wsgi setup and now everything works.

Comment: I think the confusion around the 'wsgi' directory may be that OpenShift has from memory supported different ways of supplying the WSGI script file over time. The current promoted one is to supply 'wsgi.py' in top directory. But it has also supported it being called 'wsgi/application'. In the latter case, you could also supply statics in 'wsgi/static'. Problem is that when you look at generated Apache configuration, it shows no support for '.htaccess in 'wsgi' subdirectory when using 'wsgi.py'. The scripts generating the configuration must auto adapt based on what is used.

Comment: In other words, would need to create applications for different test cases to be able to confirm what generated configuration does in each case. Makes it a little hard to reverse engineer what Apache does do when what it generates is dependent on usage.

Comment: Actually, reading https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog/ they say they got rid of wsgi/, wsgi/static/, data/ and libs/ directories. This makes it even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Graham Dumpleton's answer OpenShift supports different layouts for a Python App. If you are using the wsgi.py approach, do the following to redirect all requests to https:

```
mkdir wsgi
mv wsgi.py wsgi/application
touch wsgi/.htaccess
```

Add the following content to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on                                                                
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https                                    
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```